# Need help sorting a namedtuple and then printing the name of each namedtuple in Python

Tags: sorting, namedtuple

hello I am having some difficulty getting a function to work.

I was given a list (RL) of restaurants in namedtuples and was asked to create a function that sorts the list by alphabetically order and then returns only the name of each namedtuple.
this is what i have so far

```
def alphabetical_names(r: Restaurant) -> list:
'''returns the name of all restaurants sorted alphabetically
'''
    for restaurants in sorted(r):
        return(Restaurant.name)

print(alphabetical_names(RL))
```

However when I run this the only thing I get is 
'property object at 0x034A4A80>' and I don't know why

Comment: What results do you get? What is the definition of ``Restaurant``? Is ``r`` a single Restaurant or a list? There appear to be a number of problems with this code.

Comment: Restaurant = namedtuple('Restaurant', 'name cuisine phone dish price')    r is a list

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.

- You have declared r to be a Restaurant not a list.
- You give the variable name for the for loop a plural - this is confusing.
- Most importantly, you have referred to the Restaurant class, not the instance of the restaurant.

Try:

```
def alphabetical_names(r: list) -> list:
'''returns the name of all restaurants sorted alphabetically
'''
    for restaurant in sorted(r):
        return(restaurant.name)

print(alphabetical_names(RL))
```

However this still has a problem, as you only return the first result, not a list. So try:

```
def alphabetical_names(r: list) -> list:
'''returns the name of all restaurants sorted alphabetically
'''
    return sorted(r):

print(alphabetical_names(RL))
```

This may not sort the entries in the order you want, it is possible you will need to provide sorted a cmp function to change the sort order.

Comment: this seems to be working but now I am only receiving the first name of the list and not the whole list

Comment: I added some more details to my answer.